# How to change color of many overlapping circles in matplotlib efficiently

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I have around 1 million tiny circles plotted all with differing radii. I would like to color all circles that overlap as red, and all circles that do not overlap blue. I imagine that I could achieve this by taking the distance between the centers of each circle and then computing whether or not that distance is less than the sum of the radii of the two circles in question, but this would take a **very** long time to iterate over 1 million data points.

I am using matplotlib.patches.Circle to plot the circles. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

My attempt this far looks something like this:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='mollweide')
    plt.grid(True)
    circles = [Circle(xy=(ra[i]*np.pi/180,dec[i]*np.pi/180),radius = angle[i],color = 'red', alpha = 0.6)
              for i in range(N)]

    for c in circles:
        ax.add_artist(c)

    plt.show()
```

The output 
[image]

Comment: Maybe a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com, as the question is more about algorithm than implementation at least for now. A quick Google search does not answer the exact problem of computing the overlap for *N* disks, but stuff like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree makes one suspect there is better than N^2 complexity.